# Reverse engineering an RS-422 protocol with access to only one device?

Tags: serial, old-hardware-adaptation, reverse-engineering

I have a console, but not the main computer it's designed to connect to.

My goal is to interface this with a (Linux) PC, and hopefully more than just the keyboard. I have never tried something like this before.

So, given that I only have one half of the pair, how can I figure out what's what? How can I figure out what to *send* to it?

I know that it uses an RS-422 connection, but I know neither the data rate, the protocol, nor any commands. The probability of finding such technical data is very low, although I have access to user-level documentation (and I remember at least some of the operations from having used it back in the day).

I think I have a serial-to-usb converter, but that's probably for RS-232. I don't have (access to) an oscilloscope or signal analyzer, but I hope that some open source software exists...?

[image: Accom Axial console]

(Further details: I asked [this](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26849/advice-on-how-to-attack-my-first-reverse-engineering-project) over at Reverse Engineering, and it was suggested that you good folks may have tips.)

**EDIT:** By the way, these are the chassis: The Display chassis on top of the Comms chassis (neither of which I have, or plan to acquire).

[image: Display and Comms chassis]

Comment: pythonpython in reverse engineering has already given a very good answer.  All you need is an RS422 card for your PC.

Comment: Well, I have a laptop, and a (Chinese) serial/usb converter. But then what? I can't just `tail - f /usb`, can I? How do I figure out what to _send_?

Comment: So you are using the laptop as the comms module.  The USB/Serial needs to be RS422: not RS232.  The device will probably be /dev/ttyS0.  Have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117037/how-to-send-data-to-a-serial-port-and-see-any-answer for writing and reading from a serial port in Linux

Comment: see [plotting real time Data on (qwt )Oscillocope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21658139/2521214) there is a link to my Win32 oscilloscope,signal generator and spectral analyser using sound card (prefered sound input/output in windows) so it can be used for low freq signals up to 22KHz. If the connection is slow enough you might be able to spot and measure the signal. I upgraded the stuff to newer version which uses  192KHz as sampling rate so it can measure up to  96KHz signal If you interested comment me and I will post it somewhere.

Comment: To use it You would need windows (its was written for w2k but it works also on Xp,7,10), sound cable (I used jack 3.5 on one side and probe on the other) and probably some voltage divider / coupling (some resistors and maybe capacitor and diode) to protect the sound card from overvoltage.

Comment: Depending on what you find inside, it can be an option to read out the microcontroller's program and analyse it.

Comment: @thebusybee: I am _not_ prepared to go looking into microcode. Nope, not for me. Thanks for the angle, though!

Comment: @cup, Not _card_, Cable! USB-attached async serial adapters are cheap as dirt, and they are so small that one common form factor is, the adaptor is molded in to the USB plug on the end of a cable. https://ftdichip.com/product-category/products/cables/usb-rs422-cable-series/

Comment: Just a side note:  that thing is cool!  Please share what you end up doing with it.  I kind of want one.

Comment: @Spud  Of at you can be sure! This will take considerable (calendar) time, but I do plan to eventually submit a write-up to Hackaday! Any required sw I will need to write will end up on GitLab.

Comment: @Noughtnaut, FYI, "microcode" usually refers to a layer of code that _implements_ the visible instruction set architecture of a computer, as distinct from operating system code or application code that targets the ISA.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode

Comment: @SolomonSlow I do't sound like someone who should be messing with such things, then, eh? :) Really, this is my very first serious foray into reverse engineering, and I would rather not dive _that_ deep until I know I must. For now, at least.

Comment: @Noughtnaut, It's not that. I'm just being a nit-picker. Back in the "retro" days, when Men were Men, and CPUs were the size of commercial refrigerators, it was a lot more common for developers to have some awareness of microcode. There might be microcode upgrades for your CPU, or your site might even have custom microcode for some application. Today, if there's any microcode at all, it's buried deep in the silicon, and nobody needs to know about it or, can do anything with that knowledge, except for the architects who designed the CPU chipset.

Comment: That's all right, @SolomonSlow. I remember when my dad came home jubilant because he'd finally gotten his first hard disk -- all 16kb. Oh, the things one could _do_ with that much storage...! :)

Comment: Watch out that when you plug your USB adapter in that ModemManager doesn't go sending it Hayes commands. That is something which has bitten me in the past.

Comment: @OmarL good tip! So many traps. I've read its man page, and it seems to me that unless I need to use an _actual modem_, I could just remove `ModemManager` -- it doesn't seem to be important for networking/wifi/VPN and such.

Comment: @Noughtnaut Adding a line to an `/etc/udev/rules.d/...` file containing an adaptation of this line from my old [Teensy 2.0](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/)'s udev rules should be enough: `KERNEL=="ttyACM*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="16c0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="04[789]?", MODE:="0666", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"`

Comment: @Spud oh no, this project at got delayed indefinitely: the controller was sold to someone else! :-( I'll have to hope another one will become available.

Comment: Noooo!  Well, maybe they needed it more.  Sure was interesting to think about.  In fact, it may be worth building something like it.  After reading your note, I realize people could take various keyboard bits, SPI encoders, trackpad, sliders and all sorts of stuff and use a micro to send keyboard codes.  Or, something.

Comment: @Spud I was actually thinking of doing something like that at some point. Take one of those cheap Blue Pill development boards, Drill and bend some scrap beige flashing into an aluminum case, and mount a bunch of random controls and analog needle meters and LED bar graphs and such.

Comment: You two might want to look at what ppl are doing with custom controllers for Kebal Space Program. 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I posted a comment on the reverse-engineering Q&A you linked before I realized it'd do better as an answer here.

The answerer there found that googling Accom and Axial from your photo turns up a series of video editing controllers, and documentation for a DE-9 connector.

If it's an editing controller running RS-422 over DE-9, it's almost certainly [Sony 9-Pin Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9-Pin_Protocol) (A.K.A. P1 Protocol)... especially since the pinouts seem to match.

According to the Wikipedia page, it was a *de facto* standard in the broadcast industry until Ethernet replaced it, and "The communication parameters are 38,400 baud, 8 data bits, odd parity and 1 stop bit (38k4/8O1)".

It also links to [this document](ftp://ftp.jurassic.nl/mirrors/ftp.sgi.com/sgi/video/rld/vidpage/s9pinnt.html) which describes the communication protocol that actually runs over the serial link if you just want to get things working with minimal effort.

Comment: The linked document describes a communication protocol, where the computer acts as master and the keyboard as slave. This used to be a very common thing, not very today. It sounds like a fun project. I guess it would take either of: 1) a device driver in Linux (which in itself is an interesting project) or 2) maybe a microcomputer acting as the 422 master on one end and sending the rest into the computer as if it was a keyboard and maybe something more. Personally I would probably go with 2), maybe using a Raspberry or similar and Python.

Comment: Nice. I also tried googling "accom axial", but didn't find any protocol specs.

Comment: @ssokolow, I have no knowledge about P1 being ubiquitous, so that right there saved me a week's worth of research. The 2nd link, though, is pure gold! If that doesn't earn a check mark, I don't know what would.

Comment: @ghellquist, Why a device driver? I would have thought that async serial devices already were well supported under Linux.

Comment: @ghellquist It sounds like something that could just be done using a USB-RS422 bridge and a Python program that speaks the serial protocol on one side and uinput on the other side. (uinput is the Linux kernel's API for userspace input device drivers and is used by things like g15daemon.) ...possibly via [PySerial](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [pynput](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) so it'll work on non-Linux platforms too.

Comment: @SolomonSlow As I understand it the master (ie not the Accom device) is expected to poll the slave for information. It should send "do you have anything for me" and the device answers, as example "I have the character C from the keyboard". This can be done by a user program in Linux or Windows or whatever. But once the program in the master has the character "C" how does it send it to other programs in the master as if it came from any other keyboard. In my world that is by the device driver interface. As ssokolow writes, the device driver can be a user space program which makes it easier.

Comment: @ghellquist, OK, I get it. I had not imagined using that thing as a substitute for an ordinary keyboard, but D'Oh! if it's there on the desk, then I guess a Linux keyboard driver for it would eliminate the need to also have an ordinary keyboard beside it.

Comment: @ghellquist Precisely, which is why it might (_might!_) be useful. I know I could put a RasPi or Arduino in the console (with or without gutting the existing electronics), but I'd rather keep the original hardware as much as possible. I hope to wire this adapter to the DE-9 port (internally), and do the rest on the pc side.

Comment: @Noughtnaut No need to do it internally. Just get a USB-to-RS422 cable like Solomon Slow said, wire a DE-9 connector onto the end with the appropriate pinout (either directly if it comes with bare wires or as a custom adapter cable if it has a connector already on it), and you can have a stock Accom Axial, stock PC hardware, and all conversion done in the cable and the userspace driver. Why modify vintage tech when it's this unnecessary? (Heck, wiring custom serial cables is retro-authentic. That's why a box of unlabelled serial cables was so ominous.)

Answer (score 6):

Options:

(1) Googling "Accom axial" finds various people who bought it, made Youtube reviews etc. If these are not you, contact them and see if they have details.

(2) As has been mentioned in the comments, you need a RS422 (not RS232) adapter, e.g. to USB. The cheapest I found after a quick search is 20 EUR.

(3) You can often find the serial parameters by trying out the most often used ones. Press keys and see if you get anything. Having a scope etc. helps, but trial and error is a good substitute.

(4) Once you've seen what every keypress produces, make a list and compare them with the ones from known terminals. The `termcap` library can help. If you find similar ones, then

(5) you can guess what you can *send* to the terminal. Again, do trial and error: send a few things and see what you get back. If there's some kind of negative acknowledge for a sequence that's not understood, then even better.

Looks like a fun project.

Comment: Thank you. I'm already reaching out to the YouTube users and pro service centres, but honestly it seems the YouTube folks are generally not focused on actual operation.

Comment: Another way would be a 422 to 232 signal level converter, allowing the use of the existing 232 interface. After that it's playing with a few settings until sensible data show up - like starting with 8N1 and ignoring the top bit will cover all 7x1 transmission and so on.

Comment: @Raffzahn, this is good info for a newbie!