# Sony 9-Pin Protocol ("P2", RS-422) Help

Tags: serial, documentation

I posted this in video production as well, but it's really more of an obscure serial thing:

I have a modern SSD video recorder deck that inexplicably can only be remote controlled by RS-422 (Atomos Shogun Studio 2). It uses the Sony 9-Pin Protocol. Atomos has been no help in figuring out how to communicate with the device over serial. This is one of the better pieces of documentation out there in terms of how commands are formatted, but generally documentation of the standard that I've been able to find is pretty poor: https://www.drastic.tv/support-59/legacysoftwarehardware/37-miscellaneous-legacy/180-vvcr-422-serial-protocol

I'm using Termite to communicate with the device at 38400 baud, 8-O-1 as specified in the documentation. If I disable flow control I get a constant stream of NAK replies from the device (11 12 00 23). If I turn on RTS/CTS it will only give the NAK when I send a command, but from what I've read RTS/CTS should not be used with Sony 9-Pin/P2. My commands should be correct according to the documentation, including checksum (for instance I've tried 20 02 22 repeatedly, which should be the record command).

Can anyone with knowledge of this archaic serial protocol help me out here and let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your question is borderline off-topic since you are asking specifically about a modern device that *should be* supported by the vendor. Can you possibly re-phrase to FIRST get help in the proper usage of RS-422A between two endpoints? In other words "How do I use my modern computer to connect to a legacy RS-422A serial device?"

Comment: [This question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17758/reverse-engineering-an-rs-422-protocol-with-access-to-only-one-device) might be helpful.

Comment: Inquiring over on [ee.se](https://electronics.stackexchange.com) might also be fruitful.

Comment: Also the 2020 spec sheet for the device says that although the port is present "This feature will be added in future Firmware update".

Comment: You did not even mention what device you use to connect to the RS-422 port. Is it a RS-422 adapter, which one, and does it have the correct pinout?

Comment: Have you ever read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-422 ? It says specifically that RS-422 along with DE-9 connectors was an industry standard in video editing. So chances are there are lots of info laying around.

Answer (score 4):

The Wikipedia article for [RS-422](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-422) (linked to in @lvd's comment) links to a page on the [Sony 9-pin protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9-Pin_Protocol).  In the references for that article is a link to what appears to be a [pretty thorough description of the protocol](ftp://ftp.jurassic.nl/mirrors/ftp.sgi.com/sgi/video/rld/vidpage/s9pinnt.html).  That said, the [product information for the Shogun Studio 2](https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/uploads.atomos.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/20183006/Atomos-Shogun-Studio-2-Spec-Sheet.pdf) states that RS422 (9-pin) support "will be added in future Firmware update"; this could explain the persistent `NAK`s that you get when trying to talk to it.